# When is the function executed when using jQuery .each()?

Tags: jquery

Given the following jQuery expression

```
    $("form").each(function () {
        var info = validationInfo(this);
        if (info) {
            info.attachValidation();
        }
    });
```

The selector chooses all forms on the page, and then for each 'form' found, it attaches a function.

My question is when does the JS in this function actually run?  Does the JS in the function execute when it is attached?

Comment: I think you need to enlighten us about what `validationInfo()` and `attachValidation()` are before we can answer that question.

Comment: The JS in the function runs when it's called.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers thus far. It seems I have submitted a bad example. I would like to update that with a better one (I think it is anyway), but it would invalidate the posts that have already been given. Should I start a different thread? Or should I edit the code in the original question?  Not sure of the protocol

Comment: Just to clarify: the `.each()` method does not "attach" the function to each form. It just execute the function. When binding events the term "attaches a function" is correct, that's not the case here. The `.each()` just iterates through a collection - nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends where that code is located.

It will run if you include that code block in a `$(function(){...}` block which [runs when the document is parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908724/what-event-does-jquery-function-fire-on):

```
$(function(){
    $("form").each(function () {
        var info = validationInfo(this);
        if (info) {
            info.attachValidation();
        }
    });
})
```

Though based on your use case, you may want to validate all forms when a user event happens like clicking a button.  In that case you'd have to include the code in a function which you execute when the user clicks a button:

```
//Bind function to button
$("#mybutton").live('click', doValidation);

//Do validation
function doValidation() {
    $("form").each(function () {
        var info = validationInfo(this);
        if (info) {
            info.attachValidation();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "That code alone will never run per se."...sure it will, if it's located after any `<form>` elements...your first line is an incorrect statement.

Comment: Fair enough.  Point being it all depends where the code is placed..  updated the post..

Answer (score 2):

When is `attachValidation()` ran?  It's executed as soon as it's called in the loop.

Comment: What more was I supposed to say? It was a rather simple question deserving a rather simple answer.