# Unexpected page event execution order

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm puzzled about the execution order of the following:

```
$('#home').live('pageinit',function(){
    $('#test').hide();

    $(function() { 
        alert('test1');
    });

    $('#button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

$('#home').live('pageshow',function(){
    alert('test3');
});
```

Here is the sequence:

1. `pageinit` gets fired
2. `$('#test').hide()` is executed
3. `$('#button').click()...` is executed
4. `pageshow` and
   `alert('test3')` go off
5. `alert('test1')` is fired

Why isn't `alert('test1')` executed as number 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether any typo is there in the code but it should give you an error in the Inspect Element or Developer Console. Try enclosing the function like this:

```
(function() { 
   alert('test1');
})();
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/g8UW5/) with full source

Comment: Yes, those were typos (fixed now). The actual code is correct but has that funny sequence problem.

Comment: have you checked the fiddle, the sequence works as you want in the fiddle

Comment: it works as you say! So what's the matter with using `$(function(){});` instead? What is the mechanism that "delays" its execution?

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908724/what-event-does-jquery-function-fire-on
It's a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () { })`