# jquery document ready issue

Tags: jquery, debugging, document-ready

i wanted to know difference between both.

```
(function($){
    //some console.log code     
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //some console.log code
});
```

You guys might call me stupid but i don't know why its happening.

well here is problem.

When i use `(function($){` then i can't see any result in `console.log` but it's showing all `console debug` result when i use `document.ready`.

I am using `jQuery v1.8.2`.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908724/what-event-does-jquery-function-fire-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed something at the closing in the first example:

```
(function($){
    //some console.log code     
})(jQuery); // <----------add (jQuery) here and test it
```

or this:

```
  jQuery(function($){ // <---------add jQuery first here
    //some console.log code     
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

the first one

```
$(function(){...});  //missing $ sign here in your code
```

this is just a shorcut to call document.ready in Jquery..
both is exactly the same..
if you happen to see the core .. you will notice this in a comment...[here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L152) is the link

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
(function($){
    //some console.log code     
});
```

should be like that

```
$(function() {
    //some console.log code     
});
```

Now test it.

Refer http://api.jquery.com/ready/